# Книги по java для тех, кто после прочтения книги планирует стать среднечком

Tags: java

Желательно на русском

И хорошо бы такие, pdf версии которых можно было бы скачать или купить в инете прям сейчас. Пока бумажка доедет - ждать долго

p.s Мой уровень таков, что я немогу писать ничего тяжелее, чем усложненные helloword -ы

Comment: Java, к сожалению или к счастью, это такой язык где нет середнячков - или полные быдлокодеры или звёзды - так что вопрос напрасный.

Comment: Смотря, что понимать под словом "середнячок".

Comment: @Barmaley лучше напиши книги по java  которые точно стоит прочесть и от которых  нужно держаться подальше. а ещё лучше указать к ним базовые знания

[например что думаете о этих книгах из раздела java][1]

p.s. просто сам хочу изучить в будещем java(android) 


  [1]: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3693656

Comment: Я учил по Шилду и Ноутону, но это было очень давно. Сейчас наверняка есть и лучше книги, но я их по понятным причинам уже не читал - так что ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: @Barmaley, я так понимаю, в Java чуть стоит программисту подняться над уровнем быдлокодера и он сразу становится звездой? Хороший язык, однако.

Comment: @danpetruk "стать середнячком"...

      I find that the single thing which inhibits young professionals, new students most severely, is their acceptance of standards that are too low. If I ask a student whether her design is as good as Chartres, she often smiles tolerantly at me as if to say, “Of course not, that isn’t what I am trying to do. . . . I could never do that.”
      Then, I express my disagreement, and tell her: “That standard must be our standard...

Из предисловия C. Alexander к книге R. Gabriel "Patterns of Software"

Comment: @mikillskegg скорее наоборот - чуть зазеваешься и из уровня звезды сразу свалишься в быдлокодеры :)

Comment: @Barmaley Получается, что приложения на java -- зона особого риска? God forbid.

Comment: @danpetruk "я немогу писать ничего тяжелее, чем усложненные helloword -ы"

Тогда, может быть, следует подумать о языке, на котором не надо писать так много букв, как на java? Т.е. при том же объёме исходников функционал гораздо больше.

Comment: По-моему, если ты хочешь <заняться программированием>, тебе стоит немедленно начать программировать, а не читать книги. Нет никакого толка в таком чтении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, пожалуйста, хорошие книги по java для тех, кто хочет всерьез заняться программированием на этом языке:

- [Java 2. Библиотека профессионала,
     том 1. Основы](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1378-4.html)
- [Java 2. Библиотека
     профессионала, том 2. Тонкости
     программирования](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1482-8.html)

Сам изучал Java по ним.

Comment: @Drac5, а почему первый том Кей С. Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл не советуете (а только второй (Тонкости программирования))?

Comment: @avp , Я вообще-то ссылку на обе книги дал...

Comment: @Drac5, пардон. 

Посмотрел только на обложки и первый том того же Хорстманна не узнал. Наверное у меня другое издание...

Comment: @avp, издания 2009 и далее годов действительно имеют другую обложку. Более красочную по сравнению с оригинальной. У меня как раз старая версия, но сейчас в продаже только новые, поэтому и ссылка на новые.

Comment: второй том так себе, если честно...Да и после их прочтения всё равно середнячком не станешь, я бы назвал их книгами для начинающих.

Comment: @Viacheslav , после прочтения любой книги не станешь середнячком, так как нужно обязательно нарабатывать живой опыт программирования. Запуск программ из книг обязателен.